# Tinymce - Define a specific FONT for Headings (H1, H2 etc.)

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I'd like Headings to have a pre-defined font.  How can I do this?

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has a range of formatting options available, and the formatting includes elements like headings. The docs have some examples -> https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/

```
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',
formats: {
heading: { inline: 'h1', styles: { 'font-weight': 'bold', 'color': 'blue' } }
}
});
```

You can use CSS in the key: value format, I believe in a comma separated list. Check the section in the docs on block formats, and inline formats, since each one has different implications to the text in the editor.

!Important! UPDATE:

Using the above method will style the headings, but won't create an easy-to-use default font. Another and better way to manage this is to use the `content_css` option to setup a default style for those heading elements ([docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@content_css/)).

The first solution above would mean if you had a style update, you would need to change every header individually. However, any style changes to the `content_css` option would change each heading tag instance.

Example

tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',
formats: {
content_css: "pathway/to/style.css",
}
});

Comment: Thanks RobinJoe.

Format didn't work for me, but content_style did.  I'm using an inline setup, so perhaps that's why?

However, I noticed in a Ben Long article from 2020:

"When using TinyMCE in inline mode, we recommend you DO NOT use either of the options above."

He specifically talks about content_css and content_style: (https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-css-and-custom-styles/).

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's true - if TinyMCE is being used in Inline Mode, then do not use content_css or content_style. The CSS of the page and the CSS or Style supplied can conflict with each other. As Ben suggests, instead of a style, or a style sheet, add a class to the <div> that the editor is initialized on.